# React Router v4 Nested Routes Sub Routers

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I Have Nested Routes:

```
<TutorialsNavBarItems>
  {items.map(item => {
              const newItem = Lowercase(item);
              return (
                <Link to={`${url}/${newItem}`} key={item}>
                  <TutorialsNavBarItem
                    onClick={() => setActive(newItem)}
                    isActive={active === newItem}
                  >
                    {item}
                  </TutorialsNavBarItem>
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          </TutorialsNavBarItems>
          <Route
            path={`${url}/:tutorial`}
            render={({ match }) => <div>{match.params.tutorial}</div>}
          />
```

When user clicking any of this buttons I rendering content under this buttons.

It's works,but I have dropdown menu in my Main page.

When user has been clicked any of this items I have been render same content like I just do it before.

How I can do this ?

My Routers Structure is:

```
export default () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <HeaderPixomatic />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
        <Route exact path="/desktop-features" component={DesktopFeatures} />
        <Route path="/desktop-features/:featureName" component={DesktopFeature} />
        <Route path="/tutorials" component={Tutorials} />
        <Route path="/pricing" component={Pricing} />
        <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs} />
        <Route path="/privacy-policy-and-terms-of-use" component={OurRights} />
        <Route component={Lost} />
      </Switch>
      <FooterPixomatic />
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Where do the `items` (in the top part) come from? Do you think you can make a small stackblitz/codesandbox example

Comment: `items` just an array ..  `const items = [
  'All',
  'Background Eraser',
  'Collage Maker',
  'Crop Photo',
  'Photo cut and paste',
  'Effects for pictures',
  'Photo Retouch',
  'Youtube thumbnail'
];` I have try to make example in code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

React router v4 makes use of dynamic routing ie your new component can render if the location matches the right route.

You should show your full example or in codesandbox.